# unable to use 'JOptionPane' class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, joptionpane

[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E3ua.png)A beginner here, I was following a video tutorial, and the narrator was able to use the class but I'm not, there must be something somewhere that I'm missing please help

I suspected it might have something to do with the package or the previous class, so I created a new project, package and class and still the error was still there

Comment: Maybe have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Comment: “Screenshot of Code”  Edit your question and include your code as text, not as an image.  We cannot copy images and try the code for ourselves.  Images are also harder to read than text.

Comment: Look at the Console View. You have an unresolved compilation problem. If you want to write Java applications, build and run against a full JDK instead of the runtime that's running Eclipse.

Comment: You need to add `requires java.desktop;` to your `module-info.java`, or remove `module-info.java` to make your project non-modular and have access to all standard Java classes without declaring their modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typographical error in your code.

Rather than:

```
JOptionPane.showInput.Dialog("Enter your name");
```

your code should read:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
```

You have a stray dot (.) in your code. Java dot notation never follows a method with a class name like that.

Apparently, Eclipse has wrapped the actual error (maybe "unresolved method") in that "unresolved compilation problem" message so that it could at least attempt to run the code.

Comment: This is not the problem they are asking about; this is the problem they will face **after** solving their current problem.